# how do Iterate through the rows and print the desired output in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, loops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ5eH.png)

I tried using a for loop but it only prints out world acceptance rate for every row.

my desired output:

```
24922 YES BANK LTD (97%); NOMURA SECURITIES CO LTD (91%)
24924 ZENSAR TECHNOLOGIES LTD (97%);
25096 TUI AG (94%); CITIGROUP INC (93%); UBS INVESTMENT BANK (91%);
```

Comment: Please post your code and data (e.g. result of `print(df)`) directly to your question rather than an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This a general programming practice - you should not modify the data structure that you are iterating over in the same loop.

In your loop, you will overwrite all the values of the `company` column with the value of first row. You can overwrite your column using the `.map()` method of pandas DataFrame instead of a loop.

```py
pattern = ...
df["company"] = df["company"].map(lambda row: "".join(re.findall(pattern, row)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more idiomatic and Pandas-ish, you should avoid using `re` functions when there is alternative Pandas function performing similar functionality. These alternative Pandas functions are better optimized for vectorized operations to work with Pandas to run more efficiently.

You can use Pandas function [`str.findall()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to find all the substrings matching the pattern. Then, use [`str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) to join all these substrings.

Note that you need to slightly change your Regex to allow matching substring without a semi-colon `;` at the end. Otherwise, the substring `NOMURA SECURITIES CO LTD (91%)` (without `;` at the end) will be missing in the result when you use `findall()` on the pattern.

```
df['company'] = df['company'].str.findall(r'(.*? \((?:9\d|[1-9]\d{2,})%\);?)').str.join('')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

      id                                                        company
0  24918                                   WORLD ACCEPTANCE CORP (94%);
1  24922             YES BANK LTD (97%); NOMURA SECURITIES CO LTD (91%)
2  24924                                 ZENSAR TECHNOLOGIES LTD (97%);
3  25096  TUI AG (94%); CITIGROUP INC (93%); UBS INVESTMENT BANK (91%);
```